# Migration won't create default array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, migration

this is the migration I have problems with:

```
add_column :users, :following_categories, :integer, array: true, default: []
```

yet if the default array in migration is empty or its [1] or something else, after creating a new user it's always nil. What did I do wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Silly question: your database is postgres right? other database types don't support the array type. (just checking the basics before we try to solve the bug)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Yup, I already found out the problem is my database isn't postgres. I use pg gem for production o Heroku, so should I just move pg gem to the general (or how to call it) group? What about sqlite3 in group :development, :test ? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: It's a very good idea to have your development environment match your production environment. I'd say that you should install `postrges` on your local machine. Then install the `pg` gem - and then you can use the arrays :)

Comment: Great, thanks a lot